# Two Ruby versions simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I don't seem to be able to consistently switch between Ruby versions using rvm.  Having many gem issues--for example:

```
capybara-3.26.0 requires ruby version >= 2.4.0, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.3p222
[10:27:12] (master)
// ruby -v
ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-darwin17]
[10:27:13] (master)
// rvm list
   ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.6.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I get alternating messages that I'm using one but need the other.  I don't care which I use so long as it works.

Even after `rvm uninstall 2.3.3` I still get that I'm using 2.3.3 when trying to run `bundle`

Comment: I'm guessing you're using MacOS from the `darwin` architecture. Did you install Ruby with `homebrew` or something like that?

Comment: You may have a system ruby installed, as well as `rvm`, which is causing a conflict? If so, try removing the system ruby.

Comment: @TomLord How can I tell, and how can I do that?  All my Googling just says not to, as if I were trying to make a Horcrux.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne Not sure.  How could I tell?

Comment: What happens if you run `rvm use 2.6.0` before running bundle?

Comment: I'm no MacOS expert, but something along the lines of `brew info ruby` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced many issues with `rvm`. I switched to `asdf` and haven't looked back. I use multiple versions of Ruby, Elixir, Python, Erlang, etc. and use different versions on multiple projects. The Ruby plugin for `asdf` is [asdf-ruby](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby)